# Javascript fullscreen toggle resets user viewport position

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, fullscreen

I've got a fullscreen toggle button for a web application I'm working on, but when I toggle fullscreen on and then back off again, it resets the user's position on the page.

It's pretty jarring, as resetting the viewport position to the top of the web-page cuts off the user's access to the application about halfway, requiring them to scroll back down.

How can I modify my fullscreen toggle button to maintain a user's position on the page through fullscreen toggles?

```js
const application = document.querySelector(".application");

function toggleFullscreen(elem) {
  elem = elem || document.documentElement;
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
    !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  toggleFullscreen(application);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background: #2d2a2a;
}

#header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background: #000;
}

#spacer {
  width: 1px;
  height: 40vh;
}

#application {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 95vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<button id="fullscreenbtn">fullscreen</button>
<div id="application></div>
```

As you (hopefully) can see, the fullscreen toggle resets the viewport to the top of the page when not in fullscreen mode. I'd rather it didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the `window.pageYOffset` position when user toggles between full-screen view and regular view. Add `fullscreenchange` event listener to the global `document`. Most importantly - test it in different browsers since they all use different event names (like `mozfullscreenchange`). Add those listeners as per your supported browser list.

Here is modified code for Chrome to track and return to previous position between full screen toggle.

```
    const application = document.querySelector(".application");

    let screenOffset;
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", (event) => {
        window.scrollTo(0, screenOffset);
    });

    document.onfullscreenchange = function ( event ) {
        window.scrollTo(0, screenOffset);
    };

    function toggleFullscreen(elem) {
      elem = elem || document.documentElement;
      screenOffset = window.pageYOffset;
      if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
        !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
      } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
          document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
      }
    };

    document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      toggleFullscreen(application);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.